# Android layout weight not working as I thought

Tags: android-layout

following [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToastSimple"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="English Toast" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToastFancy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="French Toast" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The link tells me buttonToastFancy will take up three quarters of the size (3/(3+1), but it's the other way round. The buttonToastSimple takes up three quarters of the screen size according to Eclipse/my AVD.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToastSimple"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="English Toast" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToastFancy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="French Toast" />

</LinearLayout>
```

try setting the wanted attribute to `0dp` ..

ex. if you are setting the weight for the widths support, use         `android:layout_width="0dp"` along with the `android:layout_weight="3"`. Also, don't forget the `android:weightSum="4"` in the parent.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks. What was happening with my 'fill_parent' value to make it reverse everything?

Comment: welcome, can you please accept and upvote the answer if it worked.
because fill parent means to fill the available space, so when you are setting it to **1** and there is more space availabe it'll take it, rather than following its weight.

Comment: Setting width values to 0dp was just the thing that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the amount of space your view is going to occupy is computed as
dimension/layout_weight hence the view with the lower layout_weight occupies more space in your layout. in the future, you may also need to user layout_weightSum.

They are [further explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean).